# PHP Script + Cron Job causing Ubuntu to overload and crash

Tags: php, cron

I am running a cron job that goes to a page every 12 minutes and runs that, which in turn runs a PHP script.  When I go to that page via the url in a browser there is no problem, the site continues to run smoothly.  When it is executed via the cron job, the server reports this error:

```
 [Sat Oct 27 08:15:59 2012] [warn] child process 1042 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sat Oct 27 08:15:59 2012] [warn] child process 649 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sat Oct 27 08:15:59 2012] [warn] child process 1193 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
```

The script is sending posts (with links) to twitter every 12 minutes.  Could this have to do with Twitter's API?

Also here is an example of my cron job, I have tried many different ways:

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php5 /var/www/application/tweeter_omg.php
*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -q http://sitename.com/tweeter_omg
```

Comment: Which processes are 1042, 649 and 1193? Are they the last running crons?

Comment: I'm never able to figure it out, because I have to restart my server.  How can you identify a process?

Comment: Is it crashing for the first time when cron runs? If not, you can try writing proccess IDs to a text (log) file. Sorry, I haven't Linux here to try writing an example. Also you can try detect if the problem is from your twitter cron. Is everything OK with other crons?

Comment: It seems like yes to both.  I believe it occurs on the first run through the cron job, and the other crons seem to run smooth.

Comment: So, you could start with running the cron part by part until detecting what causes the problem.

Comment: You should probably start looking at the code inside `tweeter_omg.php` and while you're at it add logging to see the output of `getmypid()`. Do you have any kind of PHP logging enabled?